# Wifi Not working On Ubuntu 14.04 (Lg g3 cat6)

Tags: wireless

I installed Linux deploy on LG g3 cat6.

Using Linux deploy I ran Ubuntu 14.04 but WiFi is not working.

Does anyone know how to install drivers for wifi?

I ran the command

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

But it gave me an error.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Try `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` instead